# Historical aspect of wave theory of light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, waves, history, aether

Huygens thought light as a wave. Wave is a propagation of physical disturbance. We now know that light is electromagnetic field. Electric and magnetic field fluctuates here. What Huygens really thought? Light as a fluctuation of what?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens#Optics